# onclick function delayed trigger inside dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an onclick function in `li` element which has **data-toggle="dropdown"**. The problem here is that when i click it my function is not being called but when i click it **twice** the function is working.

[image]

i call that function to make the *scroll bar* always on *bottom* everytime a user wants to view the notification. any explanation why is it happening?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @MichaelMontero  i edited it.

Comment: IMO, you may put notifications in descending order so you don't have to scroll to the bottom.

Comment: not a good idea @PakWahWong.

Comment: Try this - onclick="scrollSmoothToBottom($event)"
Add event.stopPropogation() in your function.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
onclick = "scrollSmoothToBottom($event)"
```

JS:

```
function scrollSmoothToBottom(event) {
event.stopPropagation()
...
}
```